# HTML Video tag not working on safari and mobile phones

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, video

I have the following code for autoplaying a video on my page.

The thing is that the video works good on desktop browsers, but on desktop safari and mobile browsers it displays me only the cover image instead of playing the video.

I've tried a couple of solutions fount on internet but none of them seems to be working for me.

```
       <section class="video-bg">
        <div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9">
          <figure class="overlay">
            <video autoplay class="embed-responsive-item" poster="videos/cover.jpg">
              <source src="videos/landing_page_video_vimeo5_converted.mp4" type="video/mp4">
              <source src="videos/landing page video vimeo5.ogg" type="video/ogg">
              <source src="videos/landing page video vimeo5.ogg" type="video/webm">
            </video>
            <figcaption>
              <h1>text</h1>
              <p>text</p>
              <p>text</p>
              <p>text</p>
              <a class="video-play" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal"></a>
            </figcaption>
          </figure>
        </div>
      </section>
```

Comment: Are you able to play video directly in browser ?

Comment: In deskop browsers yes, works well. I have the problem only in ios, desktop safari, mobile chrome, mobile firefox..etc. all mobile browsers

Comment: Try to open the URL in the mobile browser mate..If it works, then add `controls` attribute to video element and tap on `Play` button..I hope it helps..

Comment: It works if i open the url ant tap play but on the page i want to autoplay not to show the play button.

Comment: As suggested in answer below, it in not possible in most of the mobile devices..No matter what you do..It will need some event initiated from user...

Comment: On iOS mobile devices - autoplay is not possible, period. User interaction is absolutely mandatory. Same goes for `<audio>`. Had tried executing this in the past with a JS based click simulation but to no avail (just FYI).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The autoplay feature is disable by Apple from iOS 6.1, see [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/safari/#documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/Using_HTML5_Audio_Video/Device-SpecificConsiderations/Device-SpecificConsiderations.html)

> In Safari on iOS (for all devices, including iPad), where the user may
>   be on a cellular network and be charged per data unit, preload and
>   autoplay are disabled. No data is loaded until the user initiates it.
>   This means the JavaScript `play()` and `load()` methods are also inactive
>   until the user initiates playback, unless the `play()` or `load()` method
>   is triggered by user action. In other words, a user-initiated Play
>   button works, but an `onLoad="play()"` event does not.

Plus this `source`

```
 <source src="videos/landing page video vimeo5.ogg" type="video/webm">
```

should be `.webm` due to your type being `video/webm`

Just a hint, try having the same name for the sources, avoiding spaces.